# State has filled with objects but cant access in return

Tags: javascript, reactjs

my 'pokemonData' state has filled with data i need but, i cant display them on screen, it just gives an empty white screen. What am I missing ?

**Here is my state variables;**

```
const [pokemonData, setPokemonData] = useState([]);
const initialUrl = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/';
```

**The whole useEffect is used for first getting a data from 'fetchData', returns a needed list of URLs which i have to fetch again in 'loadingPokemon' then i set my pokemonData state.**

```
  useEffect(() => {
   const fetchData = async () => {
   setLoading(true);
   let response = await axios.get(initialUrl);
   setNextUrl(response.next);
   setPrevUrl(response.previous);
    
   await loadingPokemon(response.data.results);
   setLoading(false);
    };
   const loadingPokemon = async (datas) => {
    let pokemonRecords = [];
    let pokemonDatas = [];
    datas.map((data) => {
     pokemonRecords.push(data.url); 
     }); 

    pokemonRecords.forEach(async (record) => {
     let pokemonDatasDatas = await axios.get(record);

    
    pokemonDatas.push(pokemonDatasDatas.data);
    });
  
    setPokemonData(pokemonDatas);
    console.log(pokemonData);
     };

    fetchData();
     }, []);

    console.log(pokemonData);
```

**Also here is my render return;**

```
return (
    <div className='App'>
      {pokemonData.map((pokemon, index) => (
       <div className='Card'>
        <div className='Card__img'>
         <img src={pokemon.sprites.front_default} alt='' />
       </div>
       <div className='Card__Name'>{pokemon.name}</div>
       <div className='Card__types'>
         {pokemon.types.map((type) => {
           return <div className='Card__type'>{type.type.name}</div>;
         })}
       </div>
       <div className='Card__info'>
         <div className='Card__data Card__data--weight'>
           <p className='title'> Weight </p>
           <p> {pokemon.weight} </p>
         </div>
         <div className='Card__data Card__data--height'>
           <p className='title'> Height </p>
           <p> {pokemon.height} </p>
         </div>
         <div className='Card__data Card__data--ability'>
           <p className='title'> Abilities </p>
           <p> {pokemon.abilities[0].ability.name} </p>
         </div>
         </div>
         </div>
          ))}
         </div>
         );
```

[image: the console log of pokemonData state]

Answer (score 0):

Try conditional rendering. I see that you are tracking your loading state, so you could use that - if data is not loading (pokemons are fetched), then list your pokemons.

Comment: oh forgot to write my 'loading' state... I tried it but didnt work, same screen...
```  return loading ? (
    <h1>loading...</h1>
  ) : (  (div...)  ```

Comment: Are you sure that is nothing wrong with your styles? check it in Elements tab in your DevTools. Something has to be rendered.

Comment: actually the 'App' div is completely empty, a bestfriend of mine said: the problem is within forEach, because even if you write async, it acts as sync function, well i saw that when i log right after forEach block and 'loadingPokemon' function continues and doesnt wait for forEach to finish its job. so we tried a for loop then await axios to fetch, it worked, i will add the answer now